# string.includes() seems not working when used on mobile(cordova)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm using cordova and I'm wondering that is the function "string.includes(str)" able to be used on mobile or not? Because it works on browser but not on mobile.

```
  $scope.place = chosenPlace;
  var appended = " London";
    //alert('before if'); this line works

  if(!($scope.place.includes(appended))) {

    //alert('start if'); this line didn't work
    $scope.place = $scope.place.concat(appended);
  }

  //alert('outside if');   this line didn't work
```

Everything works til the line alert('before if'). but it stops working when it reach if().

Comment: Try `alert(angular.toJson($scope.place))` right before the if and add what shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method works only in Chrome. You may check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Or you may check in your environment:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.includes != "undefined") { 
    // safe to use the method
}
```

Comment: You could try this: `if (!string.prototype.includes) { string.prototype.includes = function(s) { return this.indexOf(s) >= 0; } }`